# PageLoad event fires multiple times due to idletimeout plugin?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

We are having some strange issues on an asp.net web form project where the page loads and displays some data (basically a gridview).  We noticed something strange when setting a break point on a certain page in the page load event.  After about 1-2 minutes our page load event was firing again...and again..etc.  We couldn't understand why this was happening but we narrowed it down to one piece of javascript code that we are using on our site master page.

We are using the [idletimeout plugin](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-idle-timeout/example-dialog.htm) by eric hynd.  The code has some js that looks like this:

```
// cache a reference to the countdown element so we don't have to query the DOM for it on each ping.
    var $countdown = $("#dialog-countdown");
    var sessionTimeoutWarning = '<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SessionWarningInSeconds"] %>';


    // start the idle timer plugin
    $.idleTimeout('#dialog', 'div.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:first', {
        idleAfter: sessionTimeoutWarning,
        serverResponseEquals: 'OK',
        onTimeout: function () {
            window.location = "/SessionExpired.aspx";
        },
        onIdle: function () {
            $(this).dialog("open");
        },
        onCountdown: function (counter) {
            $countdown.html(counter); // update the counter
        }
    });
```

If I simply comment out this section of the code the app no longer has issues calling the page load event multiple times.  We have this code on our site.master so this happens basically to any page that uses the site master.  We did some google searching and found articles that mention similiar issues but they stated this could be caused by `img` tags that do not have a correct `src` set.  But this is not our issue, our issue is only that this idle timeout plugin is causing the page load event to fire multiple times and we are not sure why.  The minute I comment the code out everything works as normal.

Comment: can you create a plnkr.co page that reproduces the problem? or is `PageLoad` firing on the server side? if it is on the server side, then what HTTP traffic do you see in the browser console when this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The plug-in needs a `keepAliveURL:` parameter to know what service or handler to call to sustain the session.**

If you check the **[GitHub Repo](https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-idle-timeout/blob/master/src/jquery.idletimeout.js#L98)**

```
$.ajax({
        timeout: options.AJAXTimeout,
        url: options.keepAliveURL,
        error: function(){
        self.failedRequests--;
     },
     success: function(response){
        if($.trim(response) !== options.serverResponseEquals){
             self.failedRequests--;
        }
     },
     complete: function(){
         if( recurse ){
             self._startTimer();
         }
     }
 });
```

You notice the App depends on the ajax call needs

---

**To Fix:** add `keepAliveURL:` listener

```
$.idleTimeout('#dialog', 'div.ui-dialog-buttonpane button:first', {
    idleAfter: sessionTimeoutWarning,
    keepAliveURL: 'keepalive.asmx',
    serverResponseEquals: 'OK',
    onTimeout: function () {
```

The listener (any web method will do) should respond with `Content("OK")` as you have instructed:

```
serverResponseEquals: 'OK',
```

---

```
[WebMethod]
public void keepalive()
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("OK"); 
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

Comment: What should keepalive.asmx do?  Is it simply an empty file?  Can you post a full example of keepalive.asmx?

Comment: @JonH just `return Content("OK");` to tell idleTimeout that all is OK